# Chart Markers formatting for Scatter Charts

Tags: charts, office-js

Is it possible to hide the markers on an "xyscatterLines" chart like on EXCEL desktop version ? (like illustrate on images below).
[image: xyscatterLines Excel APi vs Excel desktop]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I found the solution. It is to use the "xyscatterLinesNoMarkers" chart type.